# ADF & KPSS Test Reporting Series as I(19)

Tags: stationarity, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller, differencing, kpss-test

I am currently attempting to determine the order of integration for a nonstationary time series of the Federal Funds Rate (https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/FEDFUNDS - Monthly, 1990 to 2004, 168 obs.) in R, and am using both the ADF and KPSS tests (using the `adf.test()` and `kpss.test()` commands).

When I test the undifferenced time series, I find that the time series is non-stationary. Then, I difference the time series (`df$effr %>% diff(1) %>% kpss.test()`) until I get a result that the test finds the series stationary. However, I have tested this series to a result of nonstationary until the 19th difference, where the series is finally reported to not have a unit root by the KPSS test at the 5% significance level.

Why is it taking 19 differences to make this variable stationary (is this normal? from papers I have read, orders of integration do not typically range this high), and what is the "maximum" number of differences before the results seem BS?

Comment: differencing once or twice is enough. if they don't do the trick, then there are two options: 1) find another way of obtaining stationarity. Your data is already a "rate", so I'm not sure what another possibility would be.  Maybe this is discussed in one of chatfield's writings ? 2) Resolve yourself to the fact that due to "regime changes", the data is just not stationary.  Maybe find where, assuming they exist, the structural breaks occur.

Comment: Don't test more than 2 differences because, you already have rates so , unless differences of differences of rates has some kind of meaning, I would stop after 1.

Comment: Plotting the data is also - as usual - a good idea. Conventional wisdom has it that interest rates are (at most) I(1), so something is very likely off here.

Comment: As Christoph mentioned, plotting would also give you a sense of whether there are "regime changes". Sometimes the terminology used, rather than regime change, is structural break.